# Do schemes have a characterisation as an etale space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In differential geometry, an etale bundle on a manifold $X$ is a bundle whose projection is a local homeomorphism. This can be equivalently presented as a sheaf of rings on $X$.

This can be generalised to topological spaces: There is an adjunction between $Top/X \dashv  PShf(X)$ where the left adjoint is the space of sections and the right adjoint is the space of germs. This restricts to an equivalence between $Et(X) \dashv Shf(X)$.

The definition I've seen of schemes starts from a sheaf that is valued in $Ring$ rather than $Set$: taking  $X$ to be any topological space, it is a sheaf of rings on $X$ that is locally affine - i.e. isomorphic to the spectrum of some commutative ring.

Is there equivalent a characterisation of this as an etale space? ie for every scheme $S$ is there an etale space $S'$ such that its space of sections is isomorphic to the scheme? If this isn't possible, is there a characterisation of schemes for which this is possible?

Comment: Ok, maybe you want to know if it's possible to construct an étale space (note that this is not a bundle) for sheafs with values in rings and not in sets. Is this your question? If it's so, yes this is possible. Though if you exchange ring by topological ring I don't know. About algebraic stacks, they come when you want to construct fine moduli spaces and you have to quotient by an action that is not "good" (you can think about this as in the case of orbifolds)

Comment: @user40276:yes, thats what I was thinking of; I'll edit the question.

Comment: @brandenburg: I've edited the question so hopefully its clearer

Comment: A ring is in particular a set, so you can construct its espace étalé the same way. The rest of your question still indicates some confusion about what a scheme is. A sheaf of rings can't be locally affine – that's a property of ringed spaces; a scheme is not merely a space; etc.

Comment: @Lin: according to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space) & [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ringed+space) a ringed space is a sheaf valued in rings?

Comment: No. Read carefully: "Formally, a ringed space $(X, O_X)$ is a topological space $X$ **together with** a sheaf of rings $O_X$ on $X$."

Comment: @user40276: Turns out that Maclane calls it an etale bundle in *Sheaves in Geometry & Logic*.

Comment: Yes, but it's erroneous to call this a bundle, because the fibers are discrete, unlike in the case of a principal bundle (or torsor) with a topological group acting.

Comment: Are you asking if $F\colon \text{Open}(X)^{op}\to \mathcal A$ is a $\mathcal A$-valued presheaf (where $\mathcal A$ is some algebraic category, e.g., rings) has an analogous etale morphism $\coprod F_x\to X$ as that described in Maclane so that we can define sheafification via these functors? If so, you just need to make sure the projection $p\colon \coprod F_x\to X$ respects the algebraic operations in $\mathcal A$, e.g., for rings, we must have addition, multiplication and additive inverse be continuous on fibers.

Comment: @user40276: but one can have a group with a discrete topology; or just a finite group; in which case a bundle is a covering space; also Grothendieck in his Kansas notes on fibre bundles starts with the most general possible definition of a bundle which is just a map $E \rightarrow B$ in $Top$; still, I think you're right in saying that your description is the most common.